# Update dataframe using if condition based on two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a student dataframe &  want to update the pass column value as fail where Name of student is Tom & age is 10.? Since i'm new in programming. Could anyone please suggest me what's wrong in this code? its not working.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 10,'True'], ['nick', 15,'True'], ['juli', 14,'True']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age','Pass'])

df

def result(df):
  if(df['Name']=='tom') and (df['Age']==10)):
  return 'Fail'
df2['Passs']=df2.apply(result,axis=1)
```

Comment: Where'd `df2` come from? You never declared `df2` to be a copy of `df`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
df.loc[df.Name.eq('tom') & df.Age.eq(10), 'Pass'] = 'Fail'
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   Name  Age  Pass
0   tom   10  Fail
1  nick   15  True
2  juli   14  True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['tom', 10,'True'], ['nick', 15,'True'], ['juli', 14,'True']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age','Pass'])

def myfunc(row):
    if (row.Name == 'tom') and( row.Age == 10) :
        return "Fail"
    else:
        return row.Pass

df.loc[:, 'Pass'] = df.apply(myfunc, axis = 1)
print(df)
```